# What's the best way for me to demolish & replace this existing walkway? I don't want to damage the foundation as I approach the front door!

Tags: masonry, demolition, pavers, walkway

[image][image][image]My concern is that I will accidentally damage the foundation of the house as I approach the front door.

Can I take a jackhammer to the entire walkway, right up to the front door? What's below that first layer of concrete?

Any advice that will help me replace the existing walkway with a new paver walkway would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: There should be a layer of gravel under the concrete, but if any lights/sprinklers near by, might also have wires/pipes in places.  Pictures will help.

Comment: Please use the Mountain icon in the Edit link on your question to add some pictures. As the question stands now, it is unanswerable and will probably be closed until pictures are added.

Comment: @Triplefault - added photos! Thanks for asking!

Comment: @crip659 - just added photos! Thanks for commenting on this!

Answer (score 2):

Most walkways are poured after the house is built, so it is not attached to the foundation.

Dig at the edge of the concrete close to the house until you can tell how thick the slab is.  This will give you an indication of any possible ties to the home. A thick pour, ( 6 inches or more) may have rebar tied in. The usual 4 inch walk probably not.  Your pic showed a crack at the edge of the house along the walkway, so most likely it's not tied in.

To make it easier to break up the slab drill some 1/2 inch holes in the walk close to the edge of the home to weaken it.

Start breaking the walk at the end farthest from the house and work toward the house.  A jack hammer is your friend here. Taking out the slab that way, you will find the least resistance to your demolition.  Then, if needed you can dig under the last few inches by the house. With the concrete drilled it should break away relatively easy.